# How to get the TimeZone of the local machine in JodaTime?

Tags: java, jodatime

How can I detect the timezone where a local machine is in?

I tried `DateTimeZone.getDefault()` but that does not give me eg timezone "germany" if the machine is in germany.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTimeZone.getDefault()` will return you the ID of your Timezone which should be Berlin, if your Host is located in Germany.

In the formatter you have to do something like `formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).parseDateTime(yourDateTime)` in order to have the timezone in your String.

Answer (score 1):

"germany" is not a time zone.
If your machine is in germany and you use `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()` from jdk (not from jodatime) you get "Mitteleuropäische Zeit".

If you need the country try `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry()`.